# Python Regex error: "Can't assign to operator"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to work with Python and the NLTK but cannot seem to use regular expressions for them and cannot figure out why.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import re
>>> words = nltk.corpus.words.words('en')
>>> ed-words = [w for w in words if re.search('ed$', w)]
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: You can't use `-` in a variable name... It gets processed as `ed` *minus* `words` *equals*... Use underscores to separate words... See: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers I'd also note that in your use-case, it's simpler to use `if w.endswith('ed')` as your filter condition.

Comment: I can only recall of Lisp for computer languages where a variable name containing `-` is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using `-` in a variable name is pretty much illegal in most programming languages.

In Python, you can use underscores:

```
ed_words = [w for w in words if re.search('ed$', w)]
```

See [Naming Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like a fool for missing that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `ed-words`: in Python the `-` symbol mean minus, so it's trying to process `ed - words = ...`, which is illegal.